# How to use two variables in a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, increment

```
for (int i = 0; i < ary1.length; i++) {
    int j = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter integer #"+ j++ +":" );

    ary1[i] = elementValue.nextInt();
}
```

This is part of code that allows me to input values into an array.  I want the system out to display enter integer #1 for element 0 and integer #2 for element 1 and so on.  Variable j isn't increasing although I set it to raise by one each time.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: declare j outside of this loop

Comment: You could just print "i+1", that would be the same as j starting at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need the second counter. You can do the following.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ary1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter integer #"+ (i+1) +":" );
        ary1[i] = elementValue.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried doing that initially, but my syntax was wrong because I didn't include the parentheses and tried using i += 1

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the declaration of `j` outside of the loop:

```
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < ary1.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Enter integer #"+ j++ +":" );

        ary1[i] = elementValue.nextInt();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declear the `j` var outside the loop. In you code the `j` var is assigning every time. So increment is interrupting. It should be

```
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < ary1.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter integer #"+ j++ +":" );
    ary1[i] = elementValue.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While a second variable is not needed here (and it is a bit silly because of the relationship), it is perfectly valid to "loop multiple variables", including declaring and incrementing them together:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < ary1.length; i++, j++) {
     // ..
}
```

Note that `j` is also scope to the loop (albeit with an initial value of 1), and is also incremented in the loop independently of (but at the same time as) `i`.